# Allow User to Query Database flexibly but Preventing SQL Injection

Tags: c#, sql, code-injection, sqlite-net

One of the functionality that I'm developing allows end-user to view their own database like a Database Browser. I would like to allow them to Select and Update freely but not Drop or Delete. I'm using SQLite in this project.

Currently, I did through the dummy method by checking the input beforehand.I made sure the input doesn't contain specifically 'delete ' and 'drop '.(Case-insensitive and a single space). SQLite doesn't support Truncate so I ignored that one. In this case, any record namely 'delete' or 'drop' can still be queried.

As per my understanding, Parameterization doesn't suit in this context. Please enlighten me if there's a way to workaround this. Is the current method sufficient?

Comment: Pick an ORM that fits your use case.

Comment: SQLite don't have that functionality. Since this is main functionality, you need to choose a DBMS that supports it, like mysql or such which has Users and permissions concept built in.